# How to remote into my network using some sort of second isp connection

Tags: networking, remote

My network is going down sometimes, and I need to be able to remote into the switches and look at what is going on and troubleshoot (turn off links to switches, etc).  The *inside* of the network stays up during the outage (maybe internal DoS attack or the likes)...

I'm thinking to connect a Mac Mini to my main switch with the Ethernet connection, and then use a 3G connection that I can remote to (e.g. using LogMeIn, etc). **How can I set this sort of deal up?**

Answer (score 0):

If you have the 3G connection active, you can use products like [LogMeIn](http://www.logmein.com) or [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com), which do not rely on giving out your IP address to the remote user. I use TeamViewer, and I like it. Configure it with a password, then you can access it from any other Internet connected computer, assuming the 3G connection is still active. The ID number will stay the same for the PC, so record that somewhere. If you *choose* a password, then it will not randomly generate it, and you can use the connection anytime.

Read their help file to learn more about setting it up if you need. Their help/FAQ site is quite helpful